# Is Webclient unable to download .gif files?

Tags: c#, download, webclient

Ok this is in C#, and I'm trying to download image files via url.

```
     System.Uri url = new Uri(attachments.FirstOrDefault().Url);
        string destination = @"E:\Pictures\Test\";
      using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadFile(url, destination);
                    }
```

So far, it works with .jpg, .jpeg, and .png files. But it does not work with .gif files. I am unsure of why.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"?

Comment: [`DownloadFile (Uri address, string fileName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @itsme86 As in the file does not appear in the folder.But the other file extensions work.

Comment: What's the URL? If you can download it in a web browser it should be fine via the webclient.

Comment: `client.DownloadFile(url, destination + "filename.gif");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using download file operates by looking at the ContentType in the response header, if you just want to download the file and save it with the same name that is used in the URL, then use DownloadData.

```
public static void Test()
{
    string urlString = "https://media0.giphy.com/media/o9ggk5IMcYlKE/200.gif";
    System.Uri url = new Uri(urlString);
    string destination = @"C:\Temp\";
    string[] urlSplit = urlString.Split("/");
    string filename = urlSplit[urlSplit.Length - 1];

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = wc.DownloadData(url);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destination + filename, fileBytes);
    }
}
```